# Correct way to set scrollbar position in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a basic text editor and I am saving the scroll position in a file on closing the program. Then when opening the program it will read the scroll position from the file and update it so you can continue where you left off.

I can get the position fine from `scrolledtext.yview()` which returns a tuple with e.g. (0.42, 0.75)

But I cannot figure out how to change the scroll position. I have tried `scrolledtext.vbar.set(0.42, 0.75)` to try and update it but that doesn't work as in it doesn't do anything and gives no errors. I have also tried `scrolledtext.yview(0.42, 0.75)` but it says `TclError: bad option "0.42": must be moveto or scroll` so if anyone knows how to update it that would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Edit(Code):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
Frame = frame(root)
Frame.pack()
textbox = ScrolledText(Frame)
textbox.pack()
textbox.yview()  #this is saved to file, produces tuple of e.g. (0.42, 0.75)
textbox.vbar.set(0.3, 0.7)  #this doesn't produce any errors but doesn't change the scroll position 
textbox.yview(0.3, 0.7)  #this is also something i have tried but produces the error _tkinter.TclError: bad option "0.4243827160493827": must be moveto or scroll

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you could please provide a code example of what you have tried we can better assist. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't expect the saved yview to work in all cases. If the file has been edited, the proportions could be all wrong.

The tuple you get from `yview` represents the fraction visible at the top and the fraction visible at the bottom. You can call `yview_moveto` to set the position at the top, and then let tkinter take care of the fraction at the bottom.

For example, if the yview you've saved is `(0.42, 0.75)`, then you just need to call `yview_moveto('0.42')`. This will cause the view to be adjusted so that the given offset is at the top of the window.

Comment: Thank you! It saves the last `yview` before closing the program so it should always open back up the correct position, right? Also, is there any chance you have a link to a page explaining this in more detail?

Comment: @JohnT: there's no document that explains this in more detail. However,several tkinter documentation sites mention the `yview_moveto` command and its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In case of widgets update with change bbox sizes, i use a followed snippet to keep scroll position:

```
#before repaint store vsb position caclulated in pixels from top
bbox = canvas.bbox(ALL)
self.mem_vsb_pos = canvas.yview()[0] * (bbox[3] - bbox[1])

#after repaint (back calculation):
bbox = canvas.bbox(ALL)
canvas.yview_moveto(self.do_vsb_pos / (bbox[3]-bbox[1]))

#before repaint - if need repaint from top
self.mem_vsb_pos = 0.0
```

Comment: [@Valeriy Chepelev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15368340/valeriy-chepelev)
What does `bbox[3]-bbox(https://stackoverflow.com/users/15368340/valeriy-chepelev)` mean? Why can't just `bbox[3]` be used?

Comment: @АлександрМ , at "before repaint" we store relative scroll position, so on "after repaint" we recalculate position for a new bbox size.