# Tkinter | Position scrollbar to middle

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Simple question: how can I position my (horizontal) scrollbar (`self.scrollbar`) to the center.

I know there is `self.scrollbar.set()` and but for some reason when I try this command:

```
def centerScroll(self):
    loc = self.scrollbar.get()
    self.scrollbar.set(loc[0]+0.5, loc[1]+0.5)
```

nothing happened. The scrollbar did not position to the center.

(if you want to know more about the context see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891974/tkinter-custom-widget-infinite-horizontal-scrolling-calendar))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to set scrollbar position in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157859/correct-way-to-set-scrollbar-position-in-python-tkinter). You can't do that, read the dups Answer.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The answer is to call the `set` method. If it's not working, it's a bug in your code. If we can't duplicate the problem then we can't fix it.